# Где скачать видео уроки по созданию шаблона для joomla и других CMS

Tags: wordpress, joomla, cms, drupal

Подскажите уроки по созданию шаблона для joomla ну и для других движков тоже. Сколько в сети не искал, ничего путного не нашёл.

Answer (score 1):

по друпалу  [вот это мне понравилось](http://drupal.zvirec.com/node/73), доходчиво

Answer (score 0):

А что вы подразумеваете под - *ничего путного не нашёл*? Если вы хотите создавать шаблоны на уровне [Template Monster](http://www.templatemonster.com/) или [RocketTheme](http://www.rockettheme.com/) то тут имхо одними видео уроками не обойтись, а для общего понятия можно посмотреть и на [YouTube](https://www.google.com.ua/search?client=opera&q=%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0+joomla&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest#q=%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0+joomla&hl=ru&client=opera&hs=qex&channel=suggest&prmd=imvns&source=lnms&tbm=vid&sa=X&ei=f3ntUKbRGYn4sgbWmYGoAQ&ved=0CAwQ_AUoAw&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1357316858,d.Yms&fp=bba41bd5957564e7&biw=1366&bih=684).

Comment: неужели больши никто низнает курсов по созданию шаблонов для cms?